# Cal-Heatmap Stange (incorrect) color behavior

Tags: javascript, d3.js, calendar, data-visualization, heatmap

I have a simple series of heat maps. Each with their own csv data source.

[image]

You can see a hosted example here

http://colinwhite.net/AtxUtilization/

Try examine the cells of July 14-17...

Event data is being incorrectly color coded as zero.

Can anyone help me explain and correct this strange behavior?

You can inspect the source file here

https://github.com/nyquist212/AtxUtilization/blob/master/index.html

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reduced the number of categories in the color scale seems to have resolved the problem. Beyond that, can't explain why.